# how can i pass the JSON string as a paramater for the batch class. and how can i process that in execute method

Tags: batch, json, schedulebatch

in Class, I Have JSON String containing list of sobject data more than 15000. Now i am calling batch apex class. So i have to pass that JSON string to batch class and i want to process that json and i want to insert those records. Please help.

Comment: If string is bigger then 1 MB -- SF apex will not be able to process it. I think it will be more sense to convert it to CSV and use data loader, or other data transformation tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor for the batch class and pass the JSON string parameter through that like below.

```
global class samplebatchcreateaccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String strParameter;

    public batchAccountInsert(String strParam) {
        strParameter = strParam;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'select id,Name from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {

    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

**Invocation of batch:**

```
samplebatchcreateaccount testbatch = new samplebatchcreateaccount('Testing here'); 
database.executeBatch(testbatch );
```

Comment: now i am getting the string in constructor. but how can i access that string in execute method. i am trying to access like this, System.debug('The string is'+strParameter); 
      List<codeslist> lstcodeMapping = (List<codeslist>)JSON.deserialize(strParameter, List<codeslist>.class);
    system.debug('after deserializing'+lstcodeMapping);, But the execute method is not executing.

Comment: Please avoid follow up questions in the comments, instead, post a new one with the relevant context